# How do I create an Opentip tooltip on a select list?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, prototypejs, opentip

Given this HTML (snippet):

```
<input type="text" name="sch_alert" value="foo@bar.co.uk" size="40"
maxlength="45" onchange="return valString(this.form.sch_alert, 0, 45, 'Invalid entry
for this field')" title="" id="idsch_alert"
placeholder="Your email address"><input type="text" name="sch_sms" value="44788xxxxxxx"
size="20" maxlength="14" title="" id="idsch_sms" placeholder="Your mobile number"><br>
<label class="companyform" for="idsch_all">All Campaigns?</label>
<select name="sch_all"  title="Select Yes to extract/alert for replies on all
campaigns, otherwise select No and select specific campaigns below." id="idsch_all">
<option value="Y">Yes</option>
<option value="N">No</option>
</select>
```

The following javascript works:

```
new Opentip($('idsch_alert'), 'Email to receive reply data alert', 'Alert email', {style: 'myStyle'});
new Opentip($('idsch_sms'), 'Mobile phone number', 'Alert mobile', {style: 'myStyle'});
```

But this does not:

```
new Opentip($('idsch_all'), 'Extract all data?', 'Extract', {style: 'myStyle'});
```

That last gives an error from opentip-prototype.js:

```
if (this.triggerElement.length > 1) {
  throw new Error("You can't call Opentip on multiple elements.");
}
```

I'm guessing the problem is the element length is from the number of options, since I can assign a unique ID to each of the options and then create an Opentip for each of those (albeit with positioning errors, which I could probably fix by assigning a different target).

I'm using opentip-prototype.js v2.4.6 (opentip.org)

Comment: I have found a workaround for this: enclose the select list in a span and use the ID from that:
<SPAN ID='idsch_span'><SELECT ID='idsch_all'>...</SELECT></SPAN>
If anyone can provide me with a 'proper' answer I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter for 10, if you want different tooltip for each option you could add something like for IE and chrome:

```
  <select multiple="multiple"  size="3">
            <option value="A" data-ot="AAA"> Hello</option>
            <option  value="B" data-ot="BBB">GoodBye</option>
            <option  value="C">GoodByeC</option>
            <option  value="D">GoodByeD</option>
            <option  value="E">GoodByeE</option>
            <option  value="F" data-ot="FFF">GoodByeF</option>
   </select>

 $(document).ready(
           function (event) {
               var select1 = $('SELECT option');
           if (select1.length == 0) return;
           select1 = select1[0];
           var optionToolTip = new Opentip($(select1), '', '', {});
           $('select').mousemove(function (e) {
                   var mouseY = e.offsetY;
                   //var o = document.elementFromPoint(e.PageX, e.pageY);
                   var selectHeight = this.scrollHeight;
                   var optionHeight = selectHeight / this.options.length;
                   var Y2 = mouseY + this.scrollTop;
                   var optionIndex = Math.floor(Y2 / optionHeight);
                   if (optionIndex < 0 || optionIndex >= this.options.length) {
                       optionToolTip.prepareToHide();
                       return;
                   }
                   var optionHovered = this.options[optionIndex];
                   //return new Opentip(this, content, title, options);    
                   var content = optionToolTip.adapter.data(optionHovered, "ot");
                   if ((content == null)||(content == ''))
                       optionToolTip.prepareToHide();
                   else
                   {
                       optionToolTip.setContent(content);
                       optionToolTip.prepareToShow();
                   }                   

               });

               $('select').mouseout(function (e) {
                   optionToolTip.prepareToHide();
               });
           });
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, but as I said in the OP I could assign to each option by having a unique ID for each - I was looking for a simple way to put a tooltip on the select control, and my workaround using span just feels "wrong".